# 2 + 1 dimensional gravity as an exactly soluble system

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, chern-simons-theory

In Gomez's article (Higher spin part 2) http://arXiv.org/abs/1307.3200, I face to gauge algebras. Gomez says we have some algebras for $ISO(2,1)$ and $SO(2,2)$, $SO(3,1)$.

and he tells us only  $ISO(d-1,1)$ and only for $D=3$ is a good and it is relevant and equivalent to 3D Chern-Simons.

Please give me a reference for understand it.

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible. Please try to rephrase your question such that it can be understood, explain your notation and which article you are talking about, and use [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) to typeset formulae.

Comment: You can dissolve it in water? That's pretty cool...

Comment: DON'T CLOSE THIS QUESTION! Rewrite it if necessary. There is a topic of real substance here, namely gauge theories corresponding to 2+1 gravity with various values of cosmological constant (that's the lambda).

Comment: I will try to answer it, and maybe I will suggest a rewrite of the question too, but I can't do it right away.

Comment: For the corrected formulas and another answer see http://www.physicsoverflow.org/29140

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick preliminary answer, I will fix it later.

The connection to general relativity is a change of variables in which the metric is replaced by a "spin connection" and a "frame field". These quantities can then be arranged in a new matrix, so the metric field has been rewritten as a different matrix-valued field, and the transformations (diffeomorphisms) allowed under the symmetry of general relativity (general covariance) map to gauge transformations of this new matrix-valued field. The commutation relations above, are for the group of these gauge transformations - J corresponds to translations, P to rotations and boosts. The actual group is different depending on whether we are in flat space, de Sitter space, or anti de Sitter space; the cosmological constant (which is respectively zero, positive, negative) shows up in the commutation relations as lambda. d=3 is special because only there is a gauge-invariant action for this rewrite of general relativity possible. ISO(2,1) is just the special case of lambda=0, flat space in 2+1 dimensions.

All this is scattered through section 2 of Witten's paper. Also see part 1.1 of [the sequel](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3359).

Thanks to T.S. for a discussion of this and related papers a few years ago.

Comment: Mitchell Porter thanks for your answer  it was exactly my question please give me a reference for it.

Comment: @Ali rezaie I don't have a single reference, that understanding came from many different sources. But you can do it yourself, step by step:

Comment: 1) Understand general relativity in 2+1 dimensions, in a vacuum spacetime, for the three cases.

Comment: 2) Understand the change of variables, first to spin connection and frame field, then their recombination into the new matrix.

Comment: 3) Understand how infinitesimal translations, rotations and boosts, act on the new matrix variable.

Comment: The last step should explain why the cosmological constant in the geometry becomes the structure constant in the algebra.

Comment: P.S. I just saw Arnold Neumaier's link above - it will help.

Comment: Thanks.i started in this way.but I have a one question. i am studding Higher spin Theories Part 2(Gomez)arXiv:1307.3200.in section 2 of this he describes gauge algebras and about ISO(D-1,1) tells me:it admits a non-degenerate and invariant(symmetric and real) billinear form only for D=3 and ....I can not understand it.please guide me